# Linear Homogenous Recurrences "What is the number of binary sequences of length n with no "100" "

Tags: recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

So I have a word problem I am stuck on.
I have studied linear Homogeneous and non-homogeneous recurrences fairly in depth as I have to present my findings and teach it to my senior thesis class.
the question is;

"What is the number of binary sequences of length n with no "100" ? "

so I know

The EQ (equation) for linear recurrences is

$a_n$=$c_1A_{n-1}+c_2A_{n-2}+...+c_kA_{n-k}+f(n)$

where in a homogeneous the f(n)=o

then you can use the characteristic EQ $r{^k}-c{^1}A{^{n-1}}+c{^2}A{^{n-2}}+...+c{^k}A{^{n-k}}$

so then you can find the roots and find your finished answer.(a very brief overview) 
so, I am confused on  how this word problem fits into this...

can someone point me in the right direction ??

the other word problem I am stumped on is

"What is the number of binary sequences of length n with no consecutive 00's?"

Comment: Don't teach it if you don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary sequence
with no "00"
can have its last bit 0 or 1.

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$
be the number of n-bit
binary numbers
with no 00
ending with,
respectively
0 or 1.

Figure out the recurrence
for $a_{n+1}$ and
$b_{n+1}$
in terms of
$a_n$ and $b_n$.

What you want is
$a_n+b_n$.

If you are lucky,
the recurrences will give you
a recurrence for
$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}$
in terms of $a_n+b_n$.

If not,
you will have to solve the
individual recurrences.

Have at it.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for the strings that do not contain consecutive $0$'s.
Such strings start either with $0$ or with $1$.
Call $N_1(n)$ the number of those starting with $1$.   Then those starting with $0$ shall clearly be $N_0(n)=N_1(n-1)$.
Also, those starting with $1$ will then continue with a $1$ or a $0$.

That is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  N(n) = N_{\,1} (n) + N_{\,0} (n) \hfill \cr 
  N_{\,0} (n) = N_{\,1} (n - 1) \hfill \cr 
  N_{\,1} (n) = N(n - 1) = N_{\,1} (n - 1) + N_{\,0} (n - 1) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
or
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  N(n) = N_{\,1} (n) + N_{\,0} (n) = N_{\,1} (n) + N_{\,1} (n - 1) \hfill \cr 
  N(n) = N_{\,1} (n + 1) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and finally
$$
N_{\,1} (n + 1) = N_{\,1} (n) + N_{\,1} (n - 1)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;N_{\,1} (0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \;N_{\,1} (1) = 1\; \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

You will recognize here a famous recursion.

Comment: Why did you get N(0)=0 and N(1)=1?

Comment: @MMM: if you read carefully the answer you are given, you see that $N_1$ is the number of words *starting with a $1$ and that do not contain consecutive $0$'s*: among the two words of one bit, one starts with $1$ and does not contain (consecutive) zeros, so $N_1(1)=1$.  For the empty word, then, clearly it is $N_1(0)=0$.